# how is async programming (promises) implemented in javascript? isn't javascript a ui-threaded environment?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Promises in JS allow you to do async programming, as follows:

```
DoSomething().then(success, failure);

DoSomethingElse();
```

whenever i write the previous code it reaches `DoSomethingElse()` before it reaches `success`. 
How is that possible? Isn't JS a single threaded environment (not including web-workers)? is it done with `setTimeout`?

Comment: The issue is addressed pretty well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734025/is-javascript-guaranteed-to-be-single-threaded

Comment: `async` does not imply `concurrent` that is where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, JavaScript is single-threaded, which means you should never block this single thread. Any long-running, waiting operation (typically AJAX calls or sleeps/pauses) are implemented using callbacks.

Without looking at the implementation here is what happens:

1. `DoSomething` is called and it receives `success` and `failure` functions as arguments.
2. It does what it needs to do (probably initiating long-running AJAX call) and returns
3. `DoSomethingElse()` is called
4. ...
5. Some time later AJAX response arrives. It calls previously defined `success` and `failure` function

## See also (similar problems)

- [JavaScript equivalent of SwingUtilities.invokeLater()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947034)
- [Are there any atomic javascript operations to deal with Ajax's asynchronous nature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266918)
- [jqGrid custom edit rule function using Ajax displays "Custom Function should return array!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489909)

Comment: when doing an ajax call, the xhr object is the one that's opening a new thread, so that's not really the issue.. what if it's not an ajax call? what if the long task is sorting an array for example? how is that implemented?

Comment: @EladKatz: it is not, when performing long-running CPU-intensive tasks (like sorting an array or huge DOM manipulations) the UI thread is occupied and the GUI is blocked (freezes). No timeouts are executed, no AJAX response handled, no click event handlers called. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Promises in JavaScript usually involve some kind of call chains or fluent method call APIs, where function results usually provide continuation methods like with, then, when, whenAll etc plus some status flags that indicate if the result is in fact available. Functions with input parameters can also support promised values detecting that the input is a promise and encapsulation their functionality into a thunk that can be chained when the promised value is ready.

With these you can provide an environment where promises simulate a parallel language like this:

MyApi.LongRunningTask().then( function(result) { MyAppi.LongOtherTask(result); }).then

or a sequential use case where long running calls are not dependant:

var value1 = MyApi.LongRunningTask();
var value2 = MyApi.LongRunningOtherTask();

MyApi.DoSomeFunction( value1, value2).then  ==> DoSomeFunction can check if values are ready and if not chains their then/when function to execute its logic.