# how to use jquery.validate.js to validate cells in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-validate

I have a *jqgrid*, which has multiple columns and rows, all of which are dynamically loaded. Each column has its own validation criteria, I am using **jquery.validate.js** to validate the fields. All the help that I am getting is regarding the validation done on simple form fields.

Is there any way in which jqgrid cells could be validated?

For example, I have a number field, The validation check should run each time I change focus from one cell to another in the jqgrid. I already have a mechanism running that would check if the cell is switched and what value was in that cell.

This is the code that I have to perform validation:

```
function performCellValidation(rowId, colId, colName) {
var cellValue = $grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowId, colName);
switch (colName) {
    case 'Employee_OID':
        {
            //perform validation here
        }
}
```

}

Comment: check this link out http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element

Comment: But how do I set my rules and messages against the validator? and what do I give in '#form' and '#myselect'?

Comment: check this link http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on this: [Common Editing Properties/Editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules)

in the colmodel:

```
colModel: [ 
  ... 
  {name:'Employee_OID', ..., 
   editrules: {
       custom:true,
       custom_func: function(value,colname) {
                        switch (colName) {
                            case 'Employee_OID':
                            {
                                //perform validation here
                            }
                        }
                    }
   },
   editable:true },
  ...
```

]

this may also help: [jqGrid custom edit rule function using Ajax...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489909/jqgrid-custom-edit-rule-function-using-ajax-displays-custom-function-should-ret)